# Is it possible to use the trigger written on the child object to get child records and updated parent record, when the parent record gets updated?

Tags: trigger

Let's say a parent object `Parent__c` and a child object `Child__c`, now I have a lookup field in the `Child__c`,  (for ex: `Parent_Field__c`) which links to `Parent__c`.

Now I already have a trigger written on the `Child__c`, to do some operation that uses a field(for ex: `Test_Field__c`) from `Parent__c` and after finishing that operation it updates the child record with the return value.

But now the situation is that I need to do the same operation when the `Test_Field__c` on `Parent__c` gets updated.

At present, I know that I can write a trigger on the `Parent__c` object to do this operation.

But I want to know if it is possible to do that from the `Child__c` object's trigger without writing any trigger on the `Parent__c` object. I just want to be sure if there is any salesforce documentation or workaround or anything that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Flow or Process Builder to automatically update the child records when the parent field changes. This will cause the child triggers to be called recursively. In this way, you would need no code to keep the child records updated. Make sure the Flow/Process Builder doesn't do an unnecessary update, or you might end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: is there any apex code only solution?

Comment: @Smaranjit Triggers only run when some feature forces an update. From child to parent, you can use things like Rollup Summary Fields, but from parent to child, you must do something, either a trigger, PB, or Flow.